How can I find what cookies my site uses?
I have a basic wWordpress site which doesn't even have any commenting, registration or contact forms. I collect nothing from anyone except whatever my host automatically gathers by default, like ip addresses, date and time of visit, country , operating system and as far as I can see that is all. These are all done by the host and no cookies are involved? I called my host and they told me no. But how can I check if my site uses any cookies and if so what are they?

Okay, it's not complicated, I can offer you two options right off the bat.
The first one is to use the browser's built-in tools and look there to see what cookies the site asks for when accessing the client.
The second is to use special services, the first line in Google is given as cookie-script.com
I'm sure there are more similar services out there.
And also here is a similar question on your topic on another forum.
